# javascript executing 2 times the same instruction

Tags: javascript

I'm running this piece of code:

```
if (nameHeader.length != 0) {
  nameHeader.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item != 'content-type' && item != 'Accept' && item != 'ETag' && item != 'Max-Age' && item != 'Observe') {
      console.log('-----Settaggio Opzione--------')
      coapReq.options.push({
        name: item,
        value: headers[item]
      })
    }
  })
}
console.log('Option length:' + coapReq.options.length)
```

`nameHeaders` contain ONLY one element, and the `coapReq.options vector` is empty, but after the `forEach` statement, when I print the `length` of the options vector, it print `2`.

I'm running this piece of code in the browser and on the browser's JavaScript console, beside the output `-----Settaggio Opzione--------`, there is a message saying two repetitions.

It should do just one repetition not two, because I'm sure that `nameHeader` contain only one element, but it seems that the browser is executing it 2 times.
What's happening?

Comment: Add a `console.log('nameHeader.length: '+nameHeader.length)` before the `nameHeader.forEach` and tell what the output of the console is.

Comment: You tag your question with `node.js` but in your question you write that you run the code in the browser, so how is your question related to node.js ?

Comment: Please post `nameHeader` array.

Comment: Before the code that I posted, I execute nameHeader.forEach(function(item){ console.log(item)}), and it print only one value, so I'm pretty sure that there is only one element in the nameHeader vector. The node.js tags is a mistake I have removed it, sorry.

Comment: I have inserted console.log('nameHeader.length: '+nameHeader.length) before the forEach, and it print nameHeader.length: 2 .Seems there is an additional element.